# changing text in a button when its clicked

Tags: class, button, text, nested

I have been racking my brains on how to change the text in a button after its clicked. This is for an assignment so I don't want to post the code in here. If I could just get ways of doing it, and yes I am using nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own question people....using in my listener class the following. I've been told that its not that much OO, if anyone has a better way please let me know.

class Someclass implements ActionListener
      {

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
     {
         if(button1.getText()=="OFF")
         {
             button1.setText("ON");
             }
             else{
     button1.setText("off");
  }
      }
     }
```